# django-lfs version conflict

Tags: django, django-lfs

I'm trying to install django-lfs according to the [installation instructions](http://docs.getlfs.com/en/latest/introduction/installation.html).

While running "bin/buildout -v" I have the following error:

> Installing 'djangorecipe'.
>
> We have the distribution that satisfies 'djangorecipe==1.1.2'.
>
> While:
>
> > Installing.
> >
> > Getting section django.
> >
> > Initializing section django.
> >
> > Installing recipe djangorecipe.
>
> Error: There is a version conflict.
>
> We already have: Django 1.1.1

How could I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be possible that there already is a Django installation at the system.
You could see if it can be uninstalled (via apt-get?).

Secondly, the preferred method for installing python packages is in a *virtualenv*.
This gives an isolated python environment for your specific web site where you can freely install the required package versions.